# How to read JSON in Java

Tags: java

I want to read this JSON message in Java:

```
{
    "Email": "",
    "ExpiryDate": null,
    "Folio": "",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Name": "",
    "OTBMStatus": null,
    "Return_Code": "1001",
    "Return_Message": "You cannot initiate this transaction as your ARN does not match with the last transacted broker code OR Mandate registered in the folio!",
    "ShortUrl": null,
    "TrackingNo": null
}
```

Comment: what did you do so far? please post relevant code snippets

Comment: What did you try already? You can use jackson to map the string to an object

Comment: Sir, I am calling a java bean page from jsp page